# URLSession returns the size of the data instead of the actual contents of the data

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to learn how to use URLSession, so I'm trying to get the **raw JSON** from a URL as a consistency check that it worked. But I don't understand why it's outputting the data responses **size** in bytes instead of the actual data

[Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/ozgurshn/63a59f4d241194bf6a685a3c43f7c8de) that I found online and modified to try and get it to return the JSON:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


let url = URL(string: "http://date.jsontest.com/")!
let session = URLSession.shared
let q = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    do {
        print(data!)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
q.resume()
```

This code returns something similar to
`100 bytes`, rather than the JSON itself. It doesn't make any sense, [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask) says that `data` is "The data returned by the server.", so why is it returning the size of the data instead of the JSON of the URL?

Comment: You are printing `data` with is a `Data` instance. It's normal to get that print, that's how are printed `Data` objects. Consider it as "Binary/Hex Data" at higher leve, it's up to you to interpret it: Is it an image, is it a string, etc. You want `print(String(data: data!, encoding:.utf8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a data task is always a `Data` object. It is up to you to work with it however you see fit.

For example, you could convert it into a string and print it to see what the server is sending back.

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


let url = URL(string: "http://date.jsontest.com/")!
let session = URLSession.shared
let q = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    do {
        let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("Data as JSON: ")
        print(string) // Prints the actual JSON String.
    }
    catch {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
q.resume()
```

Or perhaps more correctly you may want to parse into another object and get its properties:

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct JSONTest: Codable {
    let date: String
    let time: String
}

let url = URL(string: "http://date.jsontest.com/")!
let session = URLSession.shared
let q = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    do {
        let jsonTest = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONTest.self, from: data!)
        print("Date: \(jsonTest.date)") // Prints the `date` property of your JSON
    }
    catch {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
q.resume()
```

- To shorten the code, this question does not deal with optionals safely. Ensure you safely unwrap optionals if they can be nil.